# Something wrong with package explorer in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, class, menu, package-explorer

In package explorer whenever i open any class file from any project package explorer closed automatically. And to open it again i have to go

`Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer`

I also try

`Window -> Reset Perspective`

but its also not work. If it happens only once or twice i do not have any problem to reopen it. But on Opening every class its disappear and reopen it each time very hard. 
Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: sounds like a bug, what's the version and OS?

Comment: The `.log` file in the `.metadata` directory of the workspace may contain an error message.

Comment: latest version and window 7.

Comment: Just check that your Package Explorer view isn't opened as a "Fast view". Then it would minimize to the trim as soon as you open an editor or sets focus in another part. Right click on the title of view it to get to the menu where you can see this.

Comment: Hmm - just realized that the "latest version" likely implies Eclipse 4.3 and it doesn't have the concept of "Fast views". Back to square one..

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to completely uninstall eclipse, then reinstall it.

Comment: @fredrik Fast views still exist in 4.3 they just look/act a little different.  However, this is a good question to ask, since that may be what is happening in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just change my workspace location to other drive and its work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

It might be probably because Eclipse doesnt have enought Access Privilages on that folder.. Try Changing the workspace to another location not in the C drive.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that some plugin has caused such behavior.

Install new clean Eclipse (no new to uninstall your current).
Then try to open your project in that Eclipse, it should work OK.

Then make notice what plugins are installed, and if they change the behavior.